# Store range of cells to an Array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm working with arrays and I'm sorry but I'm a bit new to it and still confused. I have already this code to store the values in a range in an array and if I run it, it is empty.

```
attPresent = ws.Range("H4:H" & lastrow)
    ReDim attPresent(1 To UBound(attPresent))
    For k = LBound(attPresent) To UBound(attPresent)
        MsgBox attPresent(k)
    Next
```

Can someone please tell me where I'm wrong? I've read any other posts and gather some ideas, but still not working.

Comment: two things are obviously wrong. Your "array" won't be an array but a range. And the redim isn't redmimming as it used the current UBound of itself. You need to declare it as a variant and let VBA sort out the actual bounds as part of the assignment statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go like this

```
Dim attPresent as Variant
attPresent = ws.Range("H4:H" & lastrow).Value '<-- this will automatically size the array to a 2dimensional array of as many rows as the range ones and one column
For k = LBound(attPresent,1) To UBound(attPresent,1)
    MsgBox attPresent(k,1)
Next
```

Or

```
Dim attPresent as Variant
attPresent=Application.Transpose(Range("H4:H" & lastrow).Value) '<-- this will automatically size the array to a 1dimensional array of as many elements as the range
For k = LBound(attPresent) To UBound(attPresent)
    MsgBox attPresent(k)
Next
```

Comment: Why is it that there's 1 after the variant? Thanks

Comment: what _"1 after the variant"_ are you referring to?

Comment: `(attPresent,1)` variant variable i mean :)

Comment: it tells `LBound()` and `UBound()` what index to consider of the array, i.e. in this case the rows index of a 2D array. It could be actually be omitted as first index is assumed as the default one, but in multiD arrays I always explicitly declare it

Comment: Just noticed right now, the first time I run the code, it runs but if I re-run it, it returns a type mismatch error in this line: `For k = LBound(attPresent,1) To UBound(attPresent,1)`

Comment: it must be something that has to do with preceding code. If you get stuck with that, post it in a new question

Comment: If I declare it this way: `Dim attPresent() As Variant` it errors on this line `attPresent = ws.Range("H4:H" & lastrow).Value`; while if I do it this way: `Dim attPresent As Variant` it errors on this line `For k = LBound(attPresent, 1) To UBound(attPresent, 1)`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: declaring it as `Dim attPresent() As Variant`  forces you to follow up with a `ReDim` statement to size the array before using it, while by declaring `Dim attPresent As Variant` as per my advice you only need a valid range reference in `attPresent = ws.Range("H4:H" & lastrow).` to return a 2D array to loop through. In this latter case if you meet errors then it must derive from preceeding code. BTW see [this link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) link for a thorough explanation

Answer (score 2):

Reference [MSDN: ReDim Statement (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx)

When you `Redim` the array you are erasing all the values.   Use `ReDim Preserve` to resize the last dimension of the Array and still preserve the values of the array.

After the dynamic array has been allocated(the first time Redim is used) you can only resize the last dimension of a array and you cannot change the number of dimensions.  In your code you are trying to convert a 2 Dimensional array to a 1 Dimensional array, you can not do that.

You should watch this complete series: [Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).  This is the relevant video: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 25 - Arrays](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9FTX7TgkpM&index=28&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: I'm sorry but youtube is blocked from our organization :'( I'm not able to view it ..
And if I do `ReDim Preserve` it returns an error: `Subscript out of range`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    'Try this code example to suit your case
Sub StoreRangeofCellsToAnArray()
        'presumes optionbase=0
        'presume Range("a1:c3") contain number 1 to 9
        Dim MyRange, MyArray(9), n
        n = 0
        For Each c In Range("a1:c3")
        MyArray(n) = c
        n = n + 1
        Next

        'testing: reprint array
        For n = 0 To 8
        Debug.Print MyArray(n)
        Next
    End Sub
```